# TypeORM Foreign key

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys, nestjs, typeorm

I want to reference a `module` to a `queue`. So one `queue` can have multiple `modules`. Therefore I just want to store the `id` of a `module` in the `queue`.

According to the documentation of Typeorm I should implement this relation this way:

```
@ManyToOne(type => Module)
@JoinColumn({ name: "currentModuleId" })
module: Module;
```

I only want to provide the `id` of an `module`, not an modules object. So I came up with this solution:

### Modules entity

```
@Entity()
export class Module extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryColumn({ unique: true })
  public id: string;
}
```

### Queue entity

```
@Entity()
export class Queue extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  public id: string;

  @OneToOne(() => Module)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'currentModuleId' })
  currentModuleId: string;
}
```

This works, but I'm not that confident that this is an error proof solution. How should I implement a foreign key for `queue`?

**Additionaly**: How does Typeorm know on what column the `currentModuleId` should be refered?

Answer (score 6):

Many-to-one / one-to-many relations should solve your problem,

It's a relation where **A** contains multiple instances of **B**, but **B** contains only one instance of **A**.
In your case A refer to **Queue** entity and B refer to the **Module** entity

**Modules entity**

```
@Entity()
export class Module extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryColumn({ unique: true })
  public id: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => Queue, (Queue) => Queue.id, { 
    onUpdate: 'CASCADE', 
    onDelete: 'CASCADE' })
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'queues' })
  queues: Queue;

}
```

**Queue entity**

```
@Entity()
export class Queue extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  public id: string;
  
  @OneToMany(() => Module, Module => Module.queues, { 
    onUpdate: 'CASCADE', 
    onDelete: 'CASCADE' })
  modules: Module[];
}
```

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake on my side. One `queue` can have multiple `modules` is correct. Could you adapt your code?

Comment: check the code again. I hope you find this answer helpful

Comment: No, @OneToMany cannot exist without ManyToOne. If you want to use OneToMany, ManyToOne is required. However, the inverse is not required

Comment: could you write a full example

Comment: yeah, if you check the database, you will find just the queue id saved not the whole entity.